# Don't want to escape the characters while transforming XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming one XML into another form of XML using XSL.

While transforming, the non-english characters are escaped. say 'Ã' is escaped as "Atilde;".

While parsing the transformed xml, I am seeing the following error :

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "Atilde" was referenced, but not declared.

My requirement is, I don't want to allow the non-english characters to be escaped. I want to retain the characters as they are.

In the XSL that I am using to transform the XML, I have coded the below statement :

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
```

should I change any of these attributes to achieve my requirement

Comment: This sounds strange; which XSL processor are you using?. If method  is "html" the XSL processor may output HTML entities, otherwise not. Note that disabling output escaping is dangerous, since it may produce invalid XML, e.g. '<' in text is written as '<' and not '&lt;'.

Comment: Agree, this is very strange. It's either a bug, or (more likely) it's caused by something we haven't been told about. Is the XSLT processor doing the serializing, or is it writing to a DOM or similar, which is subsequently serialized by something other than XSLT?

Answer (score 4):

you need to provide a doctype

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot handle this in the `<output>` tag, but you can [chose not to escape output](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#disable-output-escaping) when you generate `text` elements in the transform. To do this use:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
```